# ddd - Where should synchronization with remote API go?

Tags: php, service, domain-driven-design

In order for my application to work, I need to synchronize regularly data from an outside service (could be an API, or a simple text file, but for now it is an API).

Since this would require creating / updating many entities at once, I need to create a Domain Service. However, I also need to create some DTOs that will contain the response of the remote API right ?

Where should this logic go ? Should I have the following directory structure:

```
Domain -
    Model - // my set of entities and repository interfaces are here
        ....
    Synchronization -
        RunSynchronizationService.php // domain service
Application
    Synchronization - 
        SynchronizeData.php // application service
        SynchronizationDataSourceInterface.php // used by application service
        MySpecificRemoteApiDataSource.php // this implements the interface above
        SynchronizationDataSourceResponse.php // this would be returned by each call of  SynchronizationDataSourceInterface method, and would contain data normalized, but not validated.
Infrastructure -
    MyConcreteImplementationOfModelEntityRepository.php
```

And when I want to synchronize the data, I smply call Application\Synchronization\SynchronizeData's sync method, wich will take a concrete implementation of SynchronizationDataSourceInterface, call its methods, and validate the returned SynchronizationDataSourceResponse objects before transferring them to Domain\Model\Synchronization\RunSynchronizationService ?

Or should I remove RunSynchronizationService (the Domain Service) and let the Application Service (SynchronizeData.php) create / update the domain entities at each step of the synchronization process ?

Comment: I might be wrong but I smell some overengineering here. My first recommendation is to isolate synchronization inside one (sub-)package. My second recommendation is why don't you start with a small service and let it evolve later when you get better understanding of its role.

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko the problem is that the synchronization process is relatively huge. I have to fetch and validate 5 to 10 responses from the API for each entity, and there are at least 700 of them

Comment: Then I would hide all the details inside the Synchronization (sub-)package. I would not put anything in the domain layer. If I understood correctly synchronization is not related to the domain but is just the way how your application works with data.

Comment: Synchronization is actually the way to provide data for the application to work, but I guess its the same

Comment: I think what Ihor might be trying to convey (and forgive me if I'm wrong, Ihor), is you should view that service as a widget you can replace with a competing vendor. So isolating the package, but defining the interaction points for your domain is more important structurally than what the service itself provides.  I'll usually create the external service instance elsewhere (such as through the app layer). Then I will pass that service into a domain operation that requires it via an interface defined in the domain or in a common area.

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey You're not wrong, it actually is a service since it is only required a few times, and the app can work if it isn't there. However, my problem is still unchanged, how to correctly design this vendor, so that I can replace my current API source by something else (a text file, or anything else) and still honor the contract needed by the domain to fulfill the sync process ?

Comment: So to understand your question more clearly (as I see you have an interface for the sync in your application layer), you're wondering if/where that  interface should be moved and where it should reside if it is moved?

Comment: @MutantNinjaCodeMonkey yes, and please tell me if I am right normalizing the interface response with a SynchronizationDataSourceResponse, and if the data it contains should indeed be validated in the application layer

Comment: Hopefully my submitted answer covers your question. Let me know if I'm missing anything and I'll try to offer further advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when presented with the question as to where an external service interface should live, I try to think of it in terms of it being another repository.  The level of abstraction I choose here will depend highly on who will use the service (just the domain/app layers of this project? other projects?), if there are different versions/vendors of the service, and how which service to use is determined.

For your example, I'm going to assume that this application is the only one using the sync service directly.  Shared services require common end points (such as the interface and output objects) to be isolated even further to avoid spilling unnecessary objects into other projects.

But in this case, to treat the service as another repository, I'd place the interface for it and standard output the domain expects and uses in the domain.

What is meant by "validation" is a little vague in your description, so I'll try to attack the different views of that here.  One or all may apply.

If validation requires you to compare against domain data, it should probably reside in the `RunSynchronizationService.php` module.  That module appears to be responsible for taking the sync data and applying it to your domain.

If validation is on the data coming back from the sync service call, and doesn't require direct access to the domain object graph, I would put that validation on the service implementation of the interface, and expose that validation call on the service interface.  To handle the situation of that validation being the same across several versions of the sync service (such as VersionA, VersionB, etc), you can use inheritance and overrides, or common helper functions to the sync service, etc.  In my example below, I used inheritance.

It could be you need to do both kinds of validation.  First check for sync data problems agnostic to the domain (on the implemented classes), and then against business rules in the domain (in `RunSynchronizationService`).  But likely both of those calls would occur in the `RunSynchronizationService` as you'd expose the sync data validation call on the interface.

The application layer should be responsible for creating the instance of the service (`MySpecificRemoteApiDataSource`), and passing it into the `RunSynchronizationService.php` module as `SynchronizationDataSourceInterface`.  If there are multiple versions, the application layer would likely be responsible for choosing which one (from a configuration, perhaps), and using a factory.

But this again highly depends on the scope of that sync service.  If you have external projects relying on it, you might want that factory part of the service layer itself so each of the other projects operate with the same choosing method.

```
Domain -
    Model - // my set of entities and repository interfaces are here
        ....
    Synchronization -
        RunSynchronizationService.php // domain service
        SynchronizationDataSourceInterface.php // used to define the contract associated with a sync service
        SynchronizationDataSourceResponse.php // this would be returned by each call of  SynchronizationDataSourceInterface method, and would contain data normalized, but not validated.
Application -  
    Synchronization - 
        SynchronizeData.php // application service - Uses a factory or some means of determining which version to use and introduce the domain to the data point.

Infrastructure -
    MyConcreteImplementationOfModelEntityRepository.php  

Synchornization -
    VersionA -  
        MySpecificRemoteApiDataSource.php  // Implements SynchronizationDataSourceInterface.php, inherits from SyncApiDataSourceBase.php
    SyncApiDataSourceBase.php  // Common logic for sync goes here, such as validation.
```

Comment: I almost did the same ! Except i put the concrete implementation of the ??`SynchronizationDatasourceInterface` in `Infrastructure/Synchronization`. Still, it is a perfectly valid answer, thanks !